# Need to fetch rows which having lowest plus some number and with out using inner or sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE "User" ( Name, Age ) AS
          SELECT 'Ira1', 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira2', 11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira3', 15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira4', 16 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira5', 17 FROM DUAL
```

I want those rows whose Age is greater than lowest Age +5. Lowest Age is 10. 
So i want all those having Age greater than 15.

The inner query which I have is.

```
select * from user
where age > (select age+5 from (select age from user order by age asc) where rownum=1);
```

Which returns:

```
Ira4      16
Ira5      17
```

Is there a way we can do it using single query. I mean no inner or sub query.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the inner query?  That desire is often based on a mis-understanding on how SQL optimiser generate execution plans.  SQL expresses logic/functionality and then the optimiser creates code to fulfil it.  You should only be targeting performance or behaviour.  Does an explain plan indicate to you that any part of this query is under-performant?

Comment: The only reason I m NOT going for inner query is, results which i have obtained is from multiple tables. And after this, I need to find lowest among the results and fetch the remaining results which are greater than lowest plus some number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code slightly by using the `MIN` aggregation function (2 table scans):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d3453/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE "User" ( Name, Age ) AS
          SELECT 'Ira1', 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira2', 11 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira3', 15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira4', 16 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira5', 17 FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "User"
WHERE  Age > ( SELECT MIN( Age ) + 5 FROM "User" )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d3453/8/0)**:

```
| NAME | AGE |
|------|-----|
| Ira4 |  16 |
| Ira5 |  17 |
```

**Query 2**:

And you can get a completely different explain plan using an analytic function (only 1 table scan):

```
SELECT Name, Age
FROM (
  SELECT u.*,
         MIN( Age ) OVER ( ORDER BY Age ) AS min_age
  FROM   "User" u
)
WHERE  Age > Min_Age + 5
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d3453/8/1)**:

```
| NAME | AGE |
|------|-----|
| Ira4 |  16 |
| Ira5 |  17 |
```

Comment: you don't need the "order by age" when doing min()

Comment: @Boneist Thanks - `MIN(Age) OVER ( ORDER BY Age )` and `MIN(Age) OVER ()` give subtly different explain plans [(SQLFIDDLE)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d43259/1) and can return the results in a different order - if the OP is that worried about performance then it is worth profiling all the options to see if any particular query is faster.

Comment: Yes, I saw that when I double-checked the difference between the two and was surprised!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an analytic function to get the minimum age, but you'd still need a subquery. It would only do one pass through the table though.

```
with usr ( Name, Age ) AS (          SELECT 'Ira1', 10 FROM DUAL
                           UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira2', 11 FROM DUAL
                           UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira3', 15 FROM DUAL
                           UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira4', 16 FROM DUAL
                           UNION ALL SELECT 'Ira5', 17 FROM DUAL)
select name,
       age
from   (select name,
               age,
               min(age) over () min_age
        from   usr)
where  age > min_age + 5;


NAME        AGE
---- ----------
Ira4         16
Ira5         17
```